# Will a Culture Bomb take a city in an adjacent tile?

Tags: civilization-5

I understand how the basic [Culture Bomb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/is-a-culture-bomb-the-only-way-to-steal-territory-from-another-civ-in-civ5) works. What I'm asking is if you own the tile adjacent to a neighboring city (other player or City State) and perform a Culture Bomb in it, will you take over that city?

In the picture below, the x's are your territory, the o's are your neighbor's, and the C is your neighbor's city.

```
x x o o o o
 x x C o o
x x(x)o o o
 x x o o o
```

If you bomb the (x) tile to change the territory like so

```
x x o o o o
 x x C o o
x x(x)x o o
 x x x o o
```

will you control the city C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this (fairly comprehensive) guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/938528-sid-meiers-civilization-v/faqs/60981), **a Culture Bomb will *not* convert a city**.  The author states that those long-range land grabs can still be useful even if they're outside of your cities' 3 tile radius utilization zone, to simply deny those resources to your enemy.

Comment: Or just splitting up their territories in different parts. You can get rich by opening your borders to them.

Comment: I confirmed this in a test game by using two Great Artists--one to get adjacent to Monty's city and the second (albeit much later because you have to wait some number of turns [30?] between Culture Bombs) to grab the city. I got the tiles on either side of the city but not the city's tile itself. Monty wasn't too pleased! Luckily he's already busy with the French and Norwegians. :)

Comment: I just used this to invade the Inca who had built the Great Wall. It allowed me to set up my units adjacent to his first city so I could take it on the same turn I declared war.