# Options to take over an AI controlled city?

Tags: civilization-5

I had an open borders agreement with an AI controlled player, and the little weasel took advantage of it to plop down a settler right smack in-between two of my cities.

Excluding a military solution, is there any way for me to take over his city?

I know that Civ 4 allowed a culture conversion of cities, but I haven't seen that yet in Civ 5. Also, this is just Civ 5 vanilla (not gods and kings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no cultural conversion of cities in Civ5.  Even the [options for taking owned tiles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/is-a-culture-bomb-the-only-way-to-steal-territory-from-another-civ-in-civ5) have been limited somewhat.

It's a terrible position for them to be in though - if they're surrounded by your boundaries, there's no way to expand their own.  Buy up whatever tiles you can to surround them, and then try to cut a deal to take over control of the city.  Usually the AI resists trades that involve cities, but they will sometimes place low value on really poorly located cities.

If it comes to war, you'll be at a significant advantage, since you'll essentially be cutting their supply lines and surrounding them with hostile units with the "friendly territory" bonuses (if you have them).

Comment: Alright, thanks. It sounds like war is the best solution. I've been itching for a fight anyway. :)

Comment: Note that you can just surround them and farm up experience for your units. Wait until they ask for peace before taking the city for your own.

Comment: Yeah, my general strategy is to let the AI march his troops into my territory like lemmings off a cliff, and then when he's begging for mercy, steamroll.