# Do you have to allocate a citizen to work a resource in order to gain access to it?

Tags: civilization-5

In [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9307/is-it-possible-to-buy-tiles-in-civilization5-that-are-more-than-3-hexes-away-from/9308#9308), Fabian said that it's enough to have an improved resource in your cultural border in order to gain access to that resource; while I was under the impression you have to actually allocate a citizen to work on the improved resource in order to get it (whether strategic or luxury), so for example you could never gain access to a resource which is farther than 3 tiles from your closest city.

I seem to remember a case where I improved a far resource and didn't get it, but I'm not so sure anymore. Which one is it, then? Do I have to actively work it or is having it within my borders enough? And if it's the latter case, can I get even further resources by using a culture bomb, which seems to be able to expand my borders even beyond 5 tiles from the nearest city?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No.

It's my experiance that simply having a tile that contains a resource **within your borders** and **with the relevant improvement constructed** (and not pillaged) is sufficent to add it to your network (it doesn't even need a road/rail connection like they did in Civ4) - this is for luxuries and strategic resources, things like sheep that just boost tile output obviously have to be worked (in the same way as you have to work a hill to get the benefit of having built a mine there).

And in a recent game I culture bombed my territory outwards in to a neutral desert area, specifically just to obtain an oil field. It was 5 tiles from my nearest city, and a soon as my worker finished building a well upon the tile I had oil available to be used for construction.

The enemy cannot block your access to the resource (say by standing units on that tile) directly, but it is quite a simple task for them to pillage the square in question, which will then cause you to lose the resource until such time as you repair the pillaged improvement.
*(With thanks to bwarner for the clarification in comments).*

Note that most (all?) resources *also* grant an output bonus to the tile they are on, and you have to work the tile from a city to get that bonus.

Comment: An enemy unit standing on your strategic resource will not cause you to lose access to it, they have to pillage it to cause you to lose access.

Comment: Thanks @bwarner, I'll adjust the answer then to factor that in.

Comment: Resources can even be farther than 3 squares from your city; as long as it's in your territory (whether due to culture bombs, or just natural growth) and it's improved, you have access to it.

Comment: apologies if this is a basic question. if access to the resources of a tile (i assume this means accessing its yield or output?) is passive, what is the purpose of allocating citizens (ie vs an active process) to work tiles? thanks.

Comment: @Abdul-KareemAbdul-Rahman In addition to whatever you get passive from a resource (Iron, for example, lets you build swordsmen), resources also provide a bonus to the tile they are on (Iron, again, increases the tile's production output) which is only collected if the tile is worked by a citizen.