# Can I use resources more than 3 tiles away from a city, but within 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I did a lot of searching and can't get a clear answer: If a resource is beyond 3 tiles but within the 5 tile border, do we still get the resource benefit? Do I have to improve it? I know it can't be worked, but if I can get the resource, and I do improve it, do I get the gold too?

I ask because I have seen resources near each other that I can get only some of them, the others are just outside.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, see [Do you have to allocate a citizen to work a resource in order to gain access to it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9313/do-you-have-to-allocate-a-citizen-to-work-a-resource-in-order-to-gain-access-to) and [How can I improve or work a resource that is more than three tiles from land?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/how-can-i-improve-or-work-a-resource-that-is-more-than-three-tiles-from-land)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can't work it so you won't get any Gold/Production/Science/etc. out of a tile 4+ away from a city.

However, in the case of strategic resources (Horses, Iron, Coal, ...) and luxury resources (Sugar, Gold, Silk, ...), they will be added to your pool if you improve the tile.

Comment: Great! Thank you! So I will improve them just so I can get the resources!!!