# What defines the boundaries of a city?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm wondering what defines part of a city. I am playing as Russia and I have 6 cities in two groups (there is only one tile separating the two, but it never wants to expand there). I have a great merchant and I want to build a customs house on a river. however I think that this river is between 4 different cities. The real question is, what cities do I receive benefits from?

If one city has every building possible (bank, market, stock exchange) and the other one is a brand new one (but still connected) which do I receive the bonuses from? Do I get bonuses from both? Does it gain bonuses from ALL connected cities? Or does it only gain bonuses from the city whose citizens work it? Suppose it's equidistant from both cities; what would happen then?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tiles-a-city-can-use-in-civ-5/7912#7912 for information about which tiles can be worked by citizens

Comment: "I am playing as Russia and I have 6 cities in two groups (there is only one tile separating the two, but it never wants to expand there)." -- I am just curious how you are doing this, I though there was a restriction in the game that no city can be less then four tiles away from each other?

Comment: @Mike - I believe the asker means that there is a tile separating the two groups of cities, so grouped because each group's boundaries form a contiguous culture area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The city that gets the bonus will be the city that works the tile. Only one city can work it at a time, and the improvement must be within three tiles of the city. Placing it between all your cities will provide the most flexibility, but beyond that will provide no more bonus than placing it next to one.

Comment: Alright. Can I manually assign citizens to work farther than 3 tiles? Or will I just have a big empty Siberia where I can't build any cities because I've already expanded onto the tile, but I can't work it because It's too far away from a city?

Comment: @Crubleigh your cities will only and can only work up to 3 tiles away from the city, also 2 cities cannot work the same tile. you can benefit from luxury and production resources through happiness or X amount of prodution resources if they are within your border yet not within range of your city. Dont think cities can expand their borders past 5 tiles away. You can see the range of how far your city can work by viewing the city all the tiles that are lite up are workable all the darker tiles are not.

Comment: @Crubleigh Also, you can build cities within your own borders as long as they are outside the 3-tile radius of other cities, so you should never end up with an "unworkable Siberia," as you put it.

Comment: @DanRasmussen It seems like a waste of a city though to put it in territory I already own. Thanks though.

Comment: @Crubleigh As you pointed out, tho, "owning" it usually means very little if it can't be worked.

Comment: In addition, you can switch the tile to another city by opening the city screen and clicking the worker assignment circle in the tile. This only works for cities you control (founded or annexed by you). While you can take tiles away from a puppet city, you can't give them back without annexing the city first.

Comment: @DavidHarkness If you unassign a forced tile that a puppet city was using, will it start using it again automatically? If not, it seems like a bug...

Comment: @DanRasmussen - The first click on the tile permanently takes control from the other city, making it available for citizens to work it either manually or by the AI. The AI will never reassign control of tiles between your cities.