# A way to increase tile working range

Tags: civilization-5

All cities have a maximum tile working radius of 3. I sometimes want to try a game with just a few enormous cities.

Is there any way, such as config file settings or mods out there that do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mod development.  Game Dev stack exchange may be able to help, though I'm pretty sure the answer to this particular question is no.

Comment: [This city working distance mod](http://www.picknmixmods.com/mods/72e3495c-054e-4a15-9c49-70e2ca197621/mod.html) is probably what you're looking for, though I'm not sure about the compatibility and I haven't tested it. Mod recommendations are still of topic, unfortunately

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the meta posts, [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797) and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question - Can this question be improved and then reopened?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to the number of tiles a city can use in Civ 5?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tiles-a-city-can-use-in-civ-5)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, without mods, there is no way to get cities with more than a range of 3 workable tiles.

Note that you can still get certain benefits from tiles that are within your borders past the three workable tiles - such as strategic and luxury resources.